# Unnest a Pandas Series without creating a combinatoric product

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     "A": [["a", "b", "c"], ["d"]], 
     "B": [[1, 2, 3], [4]], 
     "C": [["abc"], ["def"]]
    }
)
     A          B           C
0   [a, b, c]   [1, 2, 3]   [abc]
1   [d]         [4]         [def]
```

My expected output is:

```
   A  B  C
0  a  1  abc
1  b  2  abc
2  c  3  abc
3  d  4  def
```

I tried it with

```
df = df.explode("A")
df = df.explode("B")
```

But it creates a "combinatoric product" and keep the Index.

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702642/explode-multiple-columns-into-rows-maintaining-single-list-elements-order-pandas) was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a simpler solution is out there, but you can try this for now

```
newdf=df.explode("A")
newdf['B'] = df.explode("B")['B']
newdf['C'] = newdf['C'].str[0]
newdf.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**output**

```
    A   B   C
0   a   1   abc
1   b   2   abc
2   c   3   abc
3   d   4   def
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode) #.reset_index(drop=True) If required.

   A  B    C
0  a  1  abc
0  b  2  abc
0  c  3  abc
1  d  4  def
```

Comment: wow! as is said much simpler & elegant solution is indeed out there.  Up-Voted :-)

Comment: Thank you @moys ;) Your answer is also nice +1.